# Calling fnSort destroys jQuery UI tabs styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, datatables, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI tabs on one page and jQuery DataTables on several pages.  The coffeescript that creates the tabs looks like:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('#tabs').tabs()
```

The coffeescript that creates the DataTables looks like:

```
$(document).ready ->
    table = $('#table').dataTable()
    table.fnSort([[2,'desc']])
```

These are in two separate files. Since I added the call to fnSort, the tabs no longer show up properly. It looks as it would if .tabs() didn't get called at all. If I remove the fnSort line, everything works fine.

Any idea what might be going on? I am not asking for a solution to the problem; I have already found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with CoffeeScript inadvertently creating a return statement which jQuery reacts to?
Try adding an explicit 'return' statement to your callbacks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem. I added explicit return statements to both callbacks and the same issue still occurs. Thanks for the suggestion though.